# How to add callback 'after_create' in Controller which is in module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, controller

Suppose I have Controller like

```
module Module
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_user, only: %i[show]
    after_create :somemethod

   private

    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end

#Model
class User < ApplicationRecord

end
```

So when i write like this, `set_user` is not working, i mean it doesnt create user object.
Can you please help me for the same. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have a hunch that there is some other trouble you're facing here than callbacks. can you describe it more and add some code (better more than less)

Comment: The `set_user` method is probably faulty as it seems that it got called ( unless you see something like `undefined method set_user for #<SomeController:0x000055b9410c5648>`.

Please share that code or error messages.

Comment: @Pascal  I think its no-faulty. i got errors like this also.

Comment: so show all code. where is the :set_user method?

Comment: Post your some method also, because the creation might be rollback due to error in your somemethod.

Comment: after_create is a ActiveRecord callback. Not a controller method. Usually. But we don't know since we don't see the code.

Comment: When you say "not working": we don't know what that means. Is it blowing up? Is it doing something it should not. Is it not doing anything at all?
Describe your error, show error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `after_create` in a controller. You can call `after_action` or `before_action` as a filter to wrap around controller methods: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

See:

```
module Module
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    after_action :somemethod

    def show
    end

    private

    def somemethod
      puts "This will work"
    end
  end
end
```

`after_create` or any update/create/commit callback is only available for models: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html